# Keyboard shortcut bindings, pop-up context menus and TypeErrors

Tags: python, types, tkinter, contextmenu, keyboard-shortcuts

I always feel when I'm asking a question on stackoverflow like the answer... should be... RTFM, even if every answer I've ever gotten has been friendly, patient and accepting.  After an afternoon of trying to find the answer, I'm stuck.  I want to open a Tkinter, Text box and bind keys (keyboard shortcuts) and a menu items so I'll have a nice pop-up menu (aka context menu) like Window's Notepad were you right click and see

```
Cut 
Copy 
Paste 
----- 
Select All
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> as the key bindings (I haven't figured out how to do undo yet).  The problem is I can't get both the key bindings and the menu pop-up to work with the same function.  If I add or remove the "event" argument from the definition of select_all() one works but the other doesn't.

```
from Tkinter import *

# Clears the clipboard and copies the selected text to the it
def copy():
    mainwin.clipboard_clear()
    mainwin.clipboard_append(mainwin.selection_get())

# Needed for the right click pop-up menu to work, goes with copy()
def popup(event):
    popupmenu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

# Selects all text, used with the "control a" keybinding
def select_all(event):
    textbox.tag_add(SEL, "1.0", END)
    textbox.mark_set(INSERT, "1.0")
    textbox.see(INSERT)
    return 'break'

# Start of the program
mainwin = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(mainwin)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

textbox = Text(mainwin, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
textbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar.config(command=textbox.yview)

# Key bindings for the Text widget
textbox.bind("<Control-Key-a>", select_all)

# Pop-up menu, with right click binding for the Text widget
popupmenu = Menu(mainwin, tearoff=0)
popupmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=copy)
popupmenu.add_separator()
popupmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=select_all)
textbox.bind("<Button-3>", popup)

mainloop()
```

The way it's written above the key binding works, but the menu item gives me:

```
TypeError: select_all() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I could just write two functions but that seems really inefficient and doesn't explain why the program is acting this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that when you bind a function to a user-input event (such as a keypress or mouse click) and then call it with that event, it sends the event to that function. This is very useful, because maybe you want to pass the location of a mouse click to a function that's supposed to draw a dot on a canvas. However, if the click or keypress is only being used as an accelerator, then you're passing an event that isn't useful. That's not so bad by itself, but what if you also want to access that function without a keypress or mouse click - say, through a command in a menu? That won't send an event, and your function is expecting one.

There are multiple ways to solve this.

1. Define your function with `def select_all(event=None)` instead of `def select_all(event)`. This will allow your function to expect 0 or 1 arguments, defaulting to an `event` of `None` if no arguments are passed to it. (Thanks, @Bryan.)
2. Define your function with `def select_all(*event)` instead of `def select_all(event)`. This will allow your function to expect any number of positional arguments, including 0 or 1. The common name for this is `*args`, or "star args".
3. Bind the menu command with `popupmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=lambda: select_all(0))`. This defines an inline function that consists of calling the `select_all` function with one argument. That argument is garbage, but you're not using it anyway, so all is well. I think that in `tkinter` you can also bind commands with arguments with `command=select_all, 0`, but the `lambda` construction is much more popular, as it's useful outside of `tkinter` and is really a handy language feature to learn (for example, sorting an iterable by each item's second element with `sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: x[1])`).

Comment: I think `event=None` is more idiomatic than `*event`